# Restore Purchase Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to add a restore option to my app, I have a button that calls this functions:

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```

And I'm using the *paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished* function, the problem is that the function fire every time the restore button is hit whether or not the user had bought the item. How can I check if the restore was successful and that the user had bought the item?

Comment: to make IAP really work and get approved by Apple you ll need much more than this... hava a look here http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

Comment: I've already done all that, I'm only having trouble with the restore.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "How can I check if the restore was successful...". For better clarity, which scenario in this list from Apple's docs are you using and how is it failing? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html

Comment: "If your app uses non-renewing subscriptions, your app is responsible for the restoration process". I want that when i press the button a user that bought the item will receive it again and if a user pressed it and didn't buy the item he won't receive it.

Comment: Look further down the page, "Restoring Completed Transactions" -- there are three bullet items describing different scenarios; which of those three apply to you? If you're suggesting that you currently have non-renewing subscriptions and don't yet have the infrastructure to manage that yourself, that's probably more of a consulting gig than an answer here since it will be intimately tied to the code you've already written.